# How to design a REST API to fetch a large (ephemeral) data stream?

Tags: rest, stream, restful-architecture

Imagine a request that starts a long running process whose output is a large set of records.

We could start the process with a POST request:

> POST /api/v1/long-computation

The output consists of a large sequence of numbered records, that must be sent to the client. Since the output is large, the server does not store everything, and so maintains a window of records with a upper limit on the size of the window. Let's say that it stores upto 1000 records (and pauses computation whenever this many records are available). When the client fetches records, the server may subsequently delete those records and so continue with generating more records (as more slots in the 1000-length window are free).

Let's say we fetch records with:

> GET /api/v1/long-computation?ack=213

We can take this to mean that the server should return records starting from index 214. When the server receives this request, it can assume that the (well-behaved) client is acknowledging that records up to number 213 are received by the client and so it deletes them, and then returns records starting from number 214 to whatever is available at that time.

Next if the client requests:

> GET /api/v1/long-computation?ack=214

the server would delete record 214 and return records starting from 215.

This seems like a reasonable design until it is noticed that GET requests need to be safe and idempotent (see section 9.1 in the [HTTP RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)).

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to design this API?
2. Is it OK to keep it as GET even though it appears to violate the standard?
3. Would it be reasonable to make it a POST request such as:

   > POST /api/v1/long-computation/truncate-and-fetch?ack=213

Comment: 2616 is out of date. Please use RFC 723x instead.

Comment: I'm with @Evert and @EricStein that other protocols/styles are probabliy more suited. Nevertheless, HTTP offers a neat streaming solution for data that returns the same output for every client - [partial GET requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233). While the RFC more or less explains byte ranges, custom ranges like `Content-Range: "items 21-40/*"` are possible as well, though you will miss out the acknowledgement. This would have to be done differently. Note that the server does not need to store the whole result if it is able to calculate the same result segments for each client

Comment: @RomanVottner Ranges would work, but the API still needs to handle both the case where the requested range is not yet populated, and how to safely delete records so more can be created.

Comment: @EricStein The freeing of disk space so further data can be created is some implementation detail and should thus not translate to the API itself IMO. I agree though that a partial request is an edge-case of a standard GET request and servers have to support the latter while the primer is optional, hence the server has to provide the whole content in a standard GET requests, which is obviously not the case in this scenario. Due to the requirements of the protocol it is probably also infisible to teach a client to use range requests via `416 Range Not Satisfiable` responses.

Answer (score 1):

One question I always feel like that needs to be asked is, are you sure that REST is the right approach for this problem? I'm a big fan and proponent REST, but try to only apply to to situations where it's applicable.

That being said, I don't think there's anything necessarily wrong with expiring resources after they have been used, but I think it's bad design to re-use the same url over and over again.

Instead, when I call the first set of results (maybe with):

```
GET /api/v1/long-computation
```

I'd expect that resource to give me a `next` link with the next set of results.

Although that particular url design *does* sort of tell me there's only 1 long-computation on the entire system going on at the same time. If this is not the case, I would also expect a bit more uniqueness in the url design.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think this is a more pragmatic solution for me. Would using POST to convey a GET next records + DELETE older records kind of action be a bad way to design this API?

Comment: @donatello I don't think it's a very bad way to design this api, but I think at his point you just can't call it REST anymore. I think it's a reasonable design, and probably how a lot of people would design this. It's correct from a HTTP perspective

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is to buy a bigger hard drive. I'm assuming you've pushed back and that's not in the cards.

I would consider your operation to be "unsafe" as defined by [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), so I would suggest not using `GET`. I would also strongly advise you to not delete records from the server without the client explicitly requesting it. One of the principles REST is built around is that the web is unreliable. Under your design, what happens if a response doesn't make it to the client for whatever reason? If they make another request, any records from the lost response will be destroyed.

I'm going to second @Evert's suggestion that you absolutely must keep this design, you instead pick a technology that's build around reliable delivery of information, such as a messaging queue. If you're going to stick with REST, you need to allow clients to tell you when it's safe to delete records.

For instance, is it possible to page records? You could do something like:

```
POST /long-running-operations?recordsPerPage=10
202 Accepted
Location: "/long-running-operations/12"
{
    "status": "building next page",
    "retry-after-seconds": 120
}

GET /long-running-operations/12
200 OK
{
    "status": "next page available",
    "current-page": "/pages/123"
}
-- or --
GET /long-running-operations/12
200 OK
{
    "status": "building next page",
    "retry-after-seconds": 120
}
-- or --
GET /long-running-operations/12
200 OK
{
    "status": "complete"
}

GET /pages/123
{
    // a page of records
}

DELETE /pages/123
// remove this page so new records can be made
```

You'll need to cap out page size at the number of records you support. If the client request is smaller than that limit, you can background more records while they process the first page.

That's just spitballing, but maybe you can start there. No promises on quality - this is totally off the top of my head. This approach is a little chatty, but it saves you from returning a `404` if the new page isn't ready yet.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - would using POST as mentioned near the end of my question be a serious REST standards/RFC violation?

Comment: @donatello It's fine with respect to the RFC. The problem remains if the request goes through but the response does not, data is Gone and Not Recoverable short of starting the whole long-running process over again. That's a pretty negative user experience.